# Android Gallery : setPosition won't animate

Tags: android, animation, gallery, autoscroll

I've been using a gallery, and have a button that set the gallery position to some number.
I'd like my gallery to gently scroll to the defined position.

Therefore, I've been using the following command :

```
int number = 10;
mGallery.setAnimationDuration(2000);
mGallery.setPosition(number, true);
```

Should work, right ? But there is no scrolling animation : the gallery directly goes to position 10, and... that's it.
What should I do to fix such a thing ? (Except developing my own gallery...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had also tried the same thing and had view different question regarding it... it seem like the only way to animate is to use   mGallery.onfling.

After trying out the onfling, I realise that it fling to the correct position on my phone. However, when I use my friend's phone (Different Screen Size), it does not fling to the correct position. 

Do let me know if you had found the solution to it. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry, I think I dropped the subject altogether... I don't even remember why I needed this. Sorry :'(